# The thread created with newSingleThreadExecutor a newly created thread or a deamon thread?

Tags: java

want to the type of the thread created by newSingleThreadExecutor. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/concurrency/overview.html shows we can create thread 
in a single background thread (as with events in Swing) or in a newly created thread. But how to control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation of [`newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) specifies that it is (almost) the same as using [`newFixedThreadPool(1)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29), so each call to that method will create an executor with **its own thread**. That thread will not be a daemon thread by default, but you could change that by [providing your own](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29) [`ThreadFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) that produces daemon threads.

Comment: +1: In otherwords, use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29